# Link to open a Google Drive file in Sheets

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

Using the [Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/about-sdk) I can get a file's `webViewLink` to link to the file-preview in Drive, and the user can then select 'Open with Google Sheets' in the top bar to open the file up in Sheets.

Is there a way to skip that intermediary step, and link directly to that file in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you seeing in `webViewLink`?

When I try, I get

```
"webViewLink": https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1egZQnArX7TOHlQWSHiba3TTNt9Y7JoqgDAIJMdM0MQ/edit?usp=drivesdk"
```

which directly opens the sheet.

So a couple of things:-

1. **Are you sure that the file in question is a native Google spreadsheet, or is it, for example, an uploaded Excel**
2. If your webViewLink is different, you could construct the URL yourself by setting your own file's ID after the `/d/`

Comment: Hm.  `"webViewLink": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5U-iLEoLqjCZWcwdFo4WWhUakk/view?usp=drivesdk"`.  The file is an uploaded CSV, I guess that's the problem.   Using Drive's file ID in that spreadsheets url just gives a 404.   Maybe I need to figure out how to convert the CSV file in Drive to a native Google sheet before trying to open it.

Comment: Yep that's the issue. You're trying to open a non-Docs file using Docs. That's why you're getting the intermediary step.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.   I was able to auto-convert to a Sheets document by specifying the mimeType - eg `drive.create_file({mime_type: 'application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet'}, upload_source: file, content_type: 'text/csv')`

Answer (score 2):

[File.resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files#resource) also contains a link called webViewLink

> webViewLink    string  A link for opening the file in a relevant Google editor or viewer in a browser.

This will not work on all file types but it should work on sheets.

Comment: Ugh, sorry - I screwed up the original question.   I'm already using `webViewLink` (not `webContentLink` as originally asked), but that links to the Google Drive preview of the doc, rather than immediately opening the document in Sheets.   `webContentLink` immediately downloads the file, with no option to view it or open in Sheets.

Comment: these are the only two options.